# Running PowerShell from RunOnce

Tags: powershell, registry, runonce

I am trying to run a set of powershell commands during a template customization. These commands are injected into the RunOnce in the registry.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command &{Add-Type -Assembly System.Web; [Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(21,7) | Select-Object @{N="Group";E={"Test Group"}}, @{N="Username";E={"TestUser"}}, @{N="Password";E={$_}} | Export-Csv -Path C:\stuff\user.csv -NoTypeInformation}
```

I know that these commands work, as I can run them in a powershell console. I know that  "%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command &{PSCODE}" is correct because other runonce commands will run correctly. I cannot figure out what part of my syntax is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a long trial and error session, to save you precious time, I suggest you use a script file instead of that long command:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File c:\script.ps1
```

Comment: In addition, insert logging into the script to catch errors. `Start-Transcript` can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add, that in order to run a sequence of commands you have to run it without quotes. At least only in this way it worked for me:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit Import-Module Hyper-V; Get-VMSwitch \"*Virtual*\" | Remove-VMSwitch -Force; New-VMSwitch -NetAdapterName \"Ethernet\" -Name \"VMNet\"
```